# How can I prevent overlapping in nested flex div

Tags: css

I am trying to prevent that nested elements get overlapped. I want to move the second .inner div element to the right, so  first element gets more space.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item">
      <span>aaa</span>
      <span>bbb</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>aaa</span>
      <span>bbb</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>aaa</span>
      <span>bbb</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item">
      <span>ooo</span>
      <span>ooo</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See: https://codepen.io/xnsua/pen/mdpWXBY

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to the .inner class

```css
.inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    max-height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">
            <span>aaa</span>
            <span>bbb</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>aaa</span>
            <span>bbb</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>aaa</span>
            <span>bbb</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">
            <span>ooo</span>
            <span>ooo</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) for the first `.inner` div:

```css
.inner:first-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: flex-grow works.  But could I let the two .inner div  take the space which fit their content.